# Align two differently sized headers

Tags: css, material-ui

I'd like to align two headers of different sizes (ex. `h3` and `h5`) based on their bottom edge (of the word, not the div), so that it looks like a properly formatted, readable group of headers (like in a sentence). Right now, my code looks like this:

```
                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'end'
                            }}
                        >
                            <Typography variant="h3"> Sam </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ color: '#C4CDD5' }}> Jack </Typography>
                        </Box>
```

I had thought using `end` for `alignItems` might help, but it produced this picture:

[image]

The only way I can think of doing this is to use `paddingBottom` for one of the headers until their bottom edges align. However, this is tedious and wouldn't work well if I wanted to change the font size. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does align-items: baseline work instead of end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` along with `align-items: baseline`.
[More info](https://cssreference.io/property/align-items/#:%7E:text=align%2Ditems%3A%20baseline%3B,align%20along%20a%20horizontal%20line.)

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a smaller height for the h3 element so that their bottoms align together, this is what I would do